# Cannot connect to Interbase "unknown Win32 error 10060" from IDE, but works from EXE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, interbase

From inside the Delphi XE5 IDE I cannot connect to an Interbase-Server on the network:

```
Unable to complete network request to host "HOST:3054".
Failed to establish a connection.
Unknown Win32 error 10060
```

- I **can** connect to the Interbase Server using IBCONSOLE.
- I **can** connect to the Interbase server, using the EXE file from the folder.

But when I run the same EXE from **inside Delphi** (run or run with debugging) I get the above error.

The problem started when I migrated from XE4 to XE5.

These servers are running on the PC withthe interbase server:

```
Intebase XE Guardian gds_db  automatic
Intebase XE Guardian rad_xe3 manual
Intebase XE Guardian rad_xe3 manual 
Intebase XE Guardian rad_xe4 manual
Intebase XE Guardian gds_db  manual
Intebase XE Guardian rad_xe4 manual
```

I should probably uninstall the ones i don't need?

Comment: That link discusses error 10061, which seems to be [WinSock error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WSAECONNREFUSED`. Your error code 10060 is probably WinSock error `WSAETIMEDOUT`.

Comment: I had the same problem today and it was due to two instances of INterbase Running. In my case one for the Zephyr field test that I had running.

Comment: Maybe Delphi itself was blocked by firewall ? Especialyl if the firewall detected that EXE file changed and the user did not confirm the change

Comment: Delphi was blocked by the firewall, i have now enabled Embercadero to receive Connection. But it is stil not working. Maybe McAfee is blocking it?

Comment: I would check your services have started on your PC for Interbase server and Interbase Guardian. Put Guardian on as a Automatic and the server as manual.

Comment: on the client i have uninstalled all the instances of interbase. (ibconsole still works). i have edited a list of services on the PC with the interbase server.